# How to get rails variable into onclick function call

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, haml

Hi I have the following:

```
 = link_to @place.name, '#', onclick: 'get_maps(#{@location_string});'
```

I'm currently trying to link to a javascript call with a rails variable argument but for some reason the rails variable `@location_string` isn't being passed to the javascript call with the variable in it. Currently it's being rendered as a string:

```
<a href="#" onclick="get_maps(#{@location_string});">3308 Kanaina Ave</a>
```

Any thoughts on how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `#{}` syntax doesn't work inside single quotes.  You want

```
"get_maps('#{@location_string}');"
```

Comment: I don't think this is it. I changed it and the `get_maps` doesn't seem to be firing. I know `get_maps` works because when I put `onclick: 'get_maps("San Francisco");'` it does the right thing.

Comment: Ah I think you need single quotes around your `#{@location_string}` to make your code work. Change and I'll give you credit :)

Comment: Done.  Was assuming your @location_string already had the quotes.

Answer (score 5):

You need to put:

```
= link_to @place.name, '#', :onclick => "get_maps('#{@location_string}');"
```

The onclick is a parameter of link_to.
And the parameter inside get_maps should go inside ''.

Answer (score 2):

People say that using inline JS, such as onclick='', onmouseover etc. is bad. You can pass ruby variable via data attr of link and attach event using jquery click() function